# Android Studio Java Recycler View scroll to position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll

In a RecyclerView and adapter,
I get the index of the topmost item: sp = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
I go to a subfolder and back again.
And scroll back to the last top item:
smoothScrollToPosition(sp);
That's how it should work, right?
If, for example, item 3 is at the top and I scroll, item 3 should be at the top again, right?
If so, why doesn't it work for me?
I get value 3, execute smoothScrollToPosition(3) or scrollToPosition(3) and it doesn't scroll there.
Why is that?
I have removed all elements of my Acitvity.xml, had my code checked using ChatGPT, no improvement.

```
    public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    String TAG = "myTag"; // For Debug only
    private ArrayList<Item> DieItemList;
    // For Glide:
    public ClassAppSettings AppSettings = null;
    public ArrayList<ClassOneFile> FileListOne = new ArrayList<>();
    public ClassRemoteConnection DieConnection = null;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private OnCreateContextMenu onCreateContextMenu;
    private OnContextMenuItemClickListener onContextMenuItemClickListener;
    public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Item> itemList)
    {
        this.DieItemList = itemList;
    }
    public void DoSetDataList(ArrayList<Item> itemList)
    {
        this.DieItemList = itemList;
    }
    public ViewHolder DerHolder = null;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        DerHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return DerHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Item currentItem = DieItemList.get(position);
        ClassOneFile derFile = FileListOne.get(position);
        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
        holder.textView.setText(currentItem.getText());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(currentItem.getDesc());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(currentItem.isChecked());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(currentItem.getImageBitmap());
        return;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return DieItemList.size();
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener
    {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public TextView textViewDesc;
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAdapter);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAdapter);
            textViewDesc =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescAdapter);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAdapter);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (onItemClickListener != null)
            {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(v.getId() == R.id.checkBoxAdapter)
                {
                    // CHeckie:
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                    {
                        boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
                        Item i = DieItemList.get(position);
                        i.setChecked(isChecked);
                        DieItemList.set(position,i);
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                        onItemClickListener.onItemCheckBoxClick(v,position, isChecked);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                {
                    // Item:
                    //DerHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DerHolder.itemView.getContext(),R.color.black));
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition());
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
        {
            //for create context menu
            if (onCreateContextMenu != null)
            {
                //onCreateContextMenu.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo, getAdapterPosition(), onMenuItemClickListener);
                onCreateContextMenu.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo, getAdapterPosition(), null);
            }
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    interface OnItemClickListener
    {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        void onItemCheckBoxClick(View view, int position,boolean isChecked);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener)
    {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
    interface OnCreateContextMenu
    {
        void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo, int position, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener menuItemClickListener);
    }
    public void setOnCreateContextMenu(OnCreateContextMenu onCreateContextMenu)
    {
        this.onCreateContextMenu = onCreateContextMenu;
    }
    interface OnContextMenuItemClickListener
    {
        void onContextMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position);
    }
    public void setOnContextMenuItemClickListener(OnContextMenuItemClickListener onContextMenuItemClickListener)
    {
        this.onContextMenuItemClickListener = onContextMenuItemClickListener;
    }

}

    // Getting Position:
     RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = Tree.DerRecycler.getLayoutManager();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
        if(linearLayoutManager!=null)
        {
                scrollPos = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }

// and later:
Tree.DerRecycler.scrollToPosition(lastScrollPos);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My Adapter:<br>